# Issue with firebase database update using Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to update one field in my firebase db from Javascript. The code that I used is:

```
var config = {
                apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                authDomain: "yyyyyyyyy",
                databaseURL: "https://yuyuyu.firebaseio.com/",
                projectId: "demo1233xyz",
              };
              firebase.initializeApp(config);
              var database = firebase.database();

              database.ref("-UserTable/-LGDHSJSKSIUSN178").update({ verified: false });
```

But this creates a new entry in the firebase instead of updating the same record. Please find below a sample screenshot.

[image]

Can somebody help me to understand how to update an existing field in the table through Javascript.

Comment: I don't understand the contents of your "actual outcome" box.  It looks like you have two outcomes listed there.

Comment: What is happening is, the expected change is saved as a new record and the "verified: false" is not getting updated to "verified: true", instead it is added as a new record.

Comment: But you can't have two children under the same node with the same name.  That's impossible. You probably constructed the path incorrectly.  It might help if you show a screenshot of the console so it's absolutely clear what you're seeing.

Comment: Hello Doug, I have updated the screenshot with actual image. Somehow, I am not able to get the specific field updated.

Comment: be sure and `.trim` any whitespace from your variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something has an incorrect path.  One of the keys starts with a dash character, and the other does not.  Of course, you need to be using the same key in both places.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that is

```
var query = db.ref("<TABLE_NAME>").orderByChild("<FIELD>").equalTo(<VALUE>);
                 query.once("child_added", function(snapshot) {
                   snapshot.ref.update({ <FIELD>: <VALUE> })
                 });
```